# The same response for the second table

Tags: php, mysql, json

i am having a problem with my code. I am having the same response for my second table. While in the first one it goes to the next column.

**PHP**

```
$sql =  "SELECT * from schedule s, matches m GROUP BY s.id";
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
array_push($response, array("start"=>$row[4],"end"=>$row[5],"venue"=>$row[6], "teamone"=>$row[8], "teamtwo"=>$row[9], 
"s_name"=>$row[17]));

}

echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response));




mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the response i am getting. As you can see the teamone, teamtwo and s_name are all the same. It does not get the value of the second column.

```
{"schedule_response":[
{"start":"2016-11-23 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-24 00:00:00","venue":"bbbb",
 "teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"hehe","s_name":"sssss"},
{"start":"2016-11-22 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-23 00:00:00","venue":"aaaaaaa",
"teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"hehe","s_name":"sssss"}]}
```

**Schedule table**
[image]

**Matches Table**
[image]

Comment: you need to add `where s.m_id = m.m_id`

Comment: It gives me no response when i add  where s.m_id = m.m_id

Comment: `SELECT * from schedule as s, matches as m where s.m_id = m.m_id GROUP BY s.id` .  Providing you have an id in `s.m_id` that matches `m.m_id` then it should pull something.

Comment: Still the same no response

Comment: Try adding the join `SELECT * from schedule as s join matches as m where s.m_id = m.m_id GROUP BY s.id`

Comment: still the same sir

Comment: If you get empty result then your ids doesn't match (`m_id` in schedule doesn't find any related match with the same `m_id`). I assume that it's 1-to-1 relationship (tables' stucture is wrong otherwise). `GROUP BY` is not neccessary, and it gives you structurally correct result, but without any logic relation (it just filters cartesian product of two tables randomly).

Comment: It's probably because you can't group by in SQL if the others selected columns  are not aggregated. Mysql do the trick, but not properly. What happens if you remove your `GROUP BY s.id` ?

Comment: It give me a lot of response instead of just 3. and the teamone, teamtwo and s_name are still the same

Comment: Without grouping you'll get lots of rows (that usually happen with cartesian product). How your rows in these two tables are related? It looks like it should be same `m_id` (that's why you need `WHERE` condition).

Comment: Yes that's pretty normal. Now I think you've to try to join your tables without that group by. But as shudder said : "If you get empty result then your ids doesn't match [...]" you've a problem with your set of data.. `SELECT * from schedule s inner join matches m on s.m_id = m.m_id`

Comment: Thanks Julien it worked. This query also game me the same response. SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name,start,end,venue FROM matches as A right join schedule as B ON A.m_id = B.m_id

Comment: You're welcome, Yes, in your case left, right or inner join do the same because of your one-to-one relationship. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the m_id in query

```
$sql =  "SELECT * from schedule as s, matches as m where s.m_id = m.m_id GROUP BY s.id";
```

[image]

Comment: This is the same as the comment above, which the OP says is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you get "some answer" even if no data is properly linked, you need to us LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule s
LEFT JOIN matches m ON s.m_id=m.m_id
```

In this context GROUP BY might be unnecessary. Depends how your data is structured